# cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am new to programming in Java and I am currently studying method and constructor overriding. Whenever I attempt to compile the code listed at the bottom, I receive the following error message from the compiler:

> ****OverrideMethod.java:21: error: constructor OverrideMethod in class OverrideMethod cannot be applied to given types;   OverrideMethod2(int
>   x) {
>                            ^   required: int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error****

It is not until I add the constructor "OverrideMethod () { }" to the OverrideMethod class does my program compile and run. My question is, must a superclass have a default constructor without parameters defined within its class before a child class can extend it and create a constructor of its own?

```
class OverrideMethod {

    int x = 0;


    OverrideMethod(int x) {

        System.out.println("x: " + x);
    }

    void doubleX() {
        x = x*2;
    } 
}

class OverrideMethod2 extends OverrideMethod{

    OverrideMethod2(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    void doubleX() {
        super.doubleX();
        x = x*3;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class OverrideTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        OverrideMethod2 obj1 = new OverrideMethod2(5);
        obj1.doubleX();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what a super constructor invocation is?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are passing the integer along to OverrideMethod. You make a call to it's doubleX() method by calling super.doubleX(), but no where do you pass in 'x'

Comment: Sotirios, from what I understand a super constructor invocation calls a constructor from the immediate superclass. I am overriding the method from the superclasss OverrideMethod() and not really overriding the constructor. Could you please expand upon your question. Thanks.